# grep from <tag> to </tag> through multiple lines and look for a special string inside

Tags: bash, shell

I tried: `pcregrep -M '<activity.*MainActivity(\n|.)*</activity>'`

I want to grep from `<activity to </activity>` through multiple lines (3x `<activity></activity>`) and look for the string `MainActivity` between the two tags (1x `<activity MainActivity <\activity>`) and echo this one match only.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You aren't trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, now, are you?

Comment: @user3022917 which one works?

Comment: `pcregrep -M '(?s)<activity.*?MainActivity.*?<\/activity>' file` works! Awesome! Thx!

Comment: @user3022917 you should check your accept (and upvote) rate.. ;) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to the below commands,

```
pcregrep -M '(?s)<activity.*?MainActivity.*?<\/activity>' file
```

`(?s)` is a DOTALL modifier which allows dot to match even new line character also.

**OR**

```
pcregrep -M '<activity[\s\S]*?MainActivity[\s\S]*<\/activity>' file
```

`[\s\S]*` Matches any space or non-space characters zero or more times. `\n`,`\r`,`<spaces>`,`<tabs>` are matched by `\s`, so you don't need to five `\n` in your regex.